# How can I turn off the coloring of questions tagged with a "frequented tag" tag?

Tags: feature-request, tags

On StackOverflow, questions in a list of questions have a different background color when they are tagged with a tag that is listed in your favorite tags. Since yesterday (?) I see questions on ux getting a different background color.

I do not have any favorite tags set for this site, and from what I can infer the coloring is related to "Frequented tags" which has also recently shown up on the right of the questions list. The fact that I happen to read and possibly answer a lot of questions tagged with a certain tag doesn't mean I am specifically interested in that tag.

In my case it happens to be web-site design, but the questions posed and the answers I have given could also pertain to desktop design. It just so happens that the OP is working on a web-site...

Unfortunately, I don't seem to have a way of controlling this behaviour. Clicking on "set tag preferences" takes me to a page where I can add/remove favorite tags and a link to edit tag subscriptions (stackexchange filters).

I cannot find a means to turn of coloring of questions tagged with a "frequented tags" tag. Please enlighten me if there is one, or provide one if there isn't, because the coloring is putting emphasis where I don't expect/want/need it...

Comment: Why does it really matter?

Comment: @Charles: yes it matters. To me. And to me that's enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a nonsensical tag to you favorite or ignored tags.  The frequented algorithm only kicks in when both your favorite and ignored tag lists are completely empty.

Or, ya know, a real favorite/ignored tag. (:

Comment: Thanks, it shouldn't kick in at all in my (not so) humble opinion, but I'll take the work around gladly. :-)